# Looping through a JS object and confirming one of it's properties

Tags: javascript, object, iteration

I have a javascript object

```
gui: {
    windowTest: {},
    draw: function() { ... }
}
```

where windowTest is later initialised like so:

```
windowTest = new Window(x,y,w,h);
```

and the Window constructor...

```
function Window(x,y,w,h){
    this.m = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
        ...
}
```

How would I loop through the gui object and test for:

```
gui[key].m == this.m-1;
```

in another part of the code?

After looking through different questions asked on looping through JS objects, I tried this:

```
this.m = 5;
for(var key in gui){
    if(!gui.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        if(gui[key].m == this.m-1){
            //something
        }
    }
}
```

but it did nothing. I don't have any idea what the above snippet of code even does, so I couldn't possibly debug it.

Comment: remove the `!` ...

Comment: removing the ! did not help. but nevermind, i figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

this worked:

```
for(var key in gui){
    if(!gui.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
    if(gui[key].m !== undefined) {
        console.log(gui[key].m);
    }
}
```

loops through all keys in object gui, then determines if it one of the keys has the property i'm looking for, and prints it.